# What is the purpose of the reflux ratio for solvent extraction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, solvents, chemical-engineering, rare-earth-elements, industrial-chemistry

Not distillation[image: Force-feeding process for the production of an europium chloride concentrate from leach liquor derived from bastnasite.]

If I understand it correctly, in my example, one has two components, **A** and **B**, starting at the "feed" in the aqueous phase. They get both extracted in the mixer settler, but component **B** is only partially extracted.
Thus **B** goes with the raffinate to the yellow circle where the reflux ratio comes into play. The reflux ratio tells one how much goes further to processing (down) and how much is sent back with a neutralization step to the mixer settler (up). What is the purpose of this step?

**A** that was extracted in the mixer settler and **B**, if extracted, goes into the organic phase (thus moves to the right) to the stripping stage, where it is stripped into the aqueous phase (thus moves to the left). Therefore, the mixer settler concentrates **A**.

- Brown, Clifford G.; Sherrington, Leonard G. (1979): Solvent extraction used in industrial separation of rare earths. In: J. Chem. Technol. Biotechnol. 29 (4), S. 193–209. DOI: 10.1002/jctb.503290402. *

Comment: My thought is: If one imagines a reflux ratio of infinity or, in other words, nothing is going to further processing, then with time, the component in the raffinate gets more and more concentrated and pure. Thus, this would work as a batch process. If you want to have it continuous, you use a smaller reflux ratio. The trade-off is, of course, purity.

Comment: Reflux is a subpart of a distillation unit. You circled a recycle split that delivers a fraction of a product stream back upstream. The process diagram has another recycle stream up top to control solvent reuse. The recycle stream you circled is to control conversion to product. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Chemical_Engineering_Processes/Why_use_recycle%3F and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Chemical_Engineering_Processes/How_to_Analyze_a_Recycle_System

Answer (score 1):

In the context of liquid-liquid extraction, reflux may be understood as:

> "back-recirculation of the scrubbing or stripping solutions"
> [image]
> Source: https://www.mdpi.com/2075-163X/13/6/714

So instead of using pure scrubbing solution in the process shown above, you add a certain fraction of the "Solution of B".

Another [source](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0892687513003452#s0065) describes the purpose of reflux:

> To minimize the dilution of rare earth concentrations caused by the introduction of the barren aqueous scrub and the organic phase, reflux is sometimes used; some of the light rare earths from the aqueous raffinate are loaded back into the organic phase entering the first mixer settler, and some heavy rare earths are stripped from the organic product and added to the aqueous scrub.
>
> [image]

So in general, the purpose of reflux seems to be to minimize solvent and acid usage, and to make steps more efficient.

> [OP] What is the purpose of this step?

The process diagram posted by the OP is a bit puzzling because there is only one stream exiting the process. There should be another stream exiting (maybe from the stripping stages) for the solutes that are removed from the light rare earth solution. Different from the examples I show above, it seems that the reflux shown in this process concerns the organic phase, only. In the first example I show, the entirety of the organic solvent is kept in an internal loop, with aqueous solutions entering and exiting the process.

The state-of-the-art rare earth purification facilities are located in China. One report claims that the "hyperlink" technology is related to the reflux discussed here:

> In common solvent extraction processes, the acidic solvation agents are usually saponified in the organic phase by addition of a base in order to achieve the extraction, whereupon the REE are stripped from that phase by a new acidic solution in the next step. This consumes a large amounts of chemicals and creates large amounts of acidic waste. Efforts to reduce this problem include the “hyperlink process”, which is proprietary but seems to involve reuse of the organic and aqueous phases and is supposed to decrease chemical consumption and the related waste production by 30% or more. (Yan et al., 2006)

Source: Rare Earth Elements - Purification, Separation and Recycling. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316754287_Rare_Earth_Elements_-_Purification_Separation_and_Recycling [accessed Dec 28 2023].

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If I understand it correctly, the reflux is there to have a certain rare earth element concentration in your organic phase. Thus, it is a bit loaded, which makes sense in your example for scrubbing, maybe.  But in my example, I do not think so.

Comment: To add a few points: In my example, we do not have a continuous process but a batch process. Thus, after 100 h, they empty the product stages. Thus, they get a loaded aqueous phase and a loaded organic phase. With stripping, they get the rare earth from the organic into the water phase.

Comment: If I understand hyperlink technology correctly, it is the use of a different flow sheet. Fuzzy-link separation (hyperlink) is a process where the extraction focuses on the most extractable element, e.g., from a La, Ce, Pr, Nd solution Nd, and the least extractable element, La. It thus separates the feed into two fractions, La/CePr, and CePr/Nd.